# Reading JSON value problem

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

Can anyone help me can't for the life of me understand why i can't get the following to work, I am simply trying to retrieve a value from the following json:

```
{
"entities": [
    {
        "id": "84",
        "name": "jonathan",
        "date": "2009-12-12",
        "startTime": "T16:31:04",
        "endTime": "T16:31:04",
        "room": "Room1"
    },
    {
        "id": "87",
        "name": "jonathan",
        "date": "2011-12-12",
        "startTime": "T16:44:03",
        "endTime": "T16:44:03",
        "room": "Room1"
    },
    {
        "id": "90",
        "name": "jonathan",
        "date": "2011-12-12",
        "startTime": "T10:18:38",
        "endTime": "T10:18:38",
        "room": "Room1"
    }
]
}
```

I have done this a thousand times but can't access any value, been trying various variations of the following:

```
console.log(data.entities[0].id);
```

Please note I am retrieving the JSON from a dojo ajax call I am able to output the whole json to the `console`, so thats not the error.

Sure I'm doing some silly school boy error HELP !

Comment: No error in that code. What does `console.log(data.entities[0]);`, `console.log(data.entities);` and `console.log(data);` give you?

Comment: Error you are getting? Are you sure it is not being seen as a string in DOJO and not an JSON Object?

Comment: It's valid JSON, maybe you need to parse it. `JSON.parse(data).entities[0].id`

Comment: seems to work... what exactly is going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/mQNyY/

Comment: Cheers guys - just picked up some code from a collegue, pretty much when trying to reference a attribute it complains that data.entities etc. is not defined. I think there is an error somewhere else that is causing the problem. thanks for having a look :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work ok for me: http://jsfiddle.net/77W58/

It must be a problem with the `data` variable.  Is it definitely called `data`?  Is it within scope?  Is it a string rather than JSON?  Obvious really, but sometimes it's the simplest things.

Comment: thanks nick yes data definitely exists, i'm going to investigate other parts of the code as the json etc. looks fine. cheers

Answer (score 0):

what does your ajax request look like?  If you don't have the property handleAs: 'json', the response will come back as text.  In this case if you console.log the response, you'll see the response, but it won't be typed as an object.

```
dojo.xhrPost({
  url: '/something',
  handleAs: 'json',
  load: function(data){
   //this should show up as an Object in the console
   console.log(data);
  }

});
```

Vs

```
dojo.xhrPost({
  url: '/something',
  //optional, defaults to this property
  handleAs: 'text',
  load: function(data){
   //this should show up as a string in the console
   console.log(data);
  }

});
```